# Print.myclass function in R

Tags: r, function, package

I am trying to develop my first package in R and I am facing some issues with `"myclass"` generic functions that i will try to describe.

Assume a data.frame `X` with `n <- nrow(X)` rows and `K <- ncol(X)` columns.

My main package function (too big to put it in this post) lets say

```
fun1 <- function(X){
   # do staff...
   out <- list(index= character vector, A= A, B= B,... etc)
   return(out)
   class(out) <- "myclass"
}
```

returns as an output a list. Then I have to use the output for the generic print method in a `print.myclass` function. However, in my print function I want to use the data frame `X` used in my main function without asking the user to provide it in an argument (i.e, `print(out,X)`) and without having it in my output list `out` (visible to the user at least). Is there any way to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't want to leave any track of the object (that could even be non existing when `print` is called) from which the instance of your class has been created, I guess that your requirement is very hard to meet... Is there a way to "reverse-engineer" `X` from the `myclass` object?

Comment: Also, in the question, `return(out)` and the following line must be switched.

Comment: Thank you for the response....i was thinking for a kind of hidden output in my main function where I can access it in my `print.myclass` function. I gave a look at the `elipsis` (`...`) function structure and in the `capture.output`  but it was not clear if these functions can be helpfull in my case.

Comment: For the order of the commands in my function... if i change the order then when i use `fun1(X)` i get the output of the print and not the list() that I suppose to get as `return` value...or i do something terribly wrong...

Comment: Which `print` are you talking about? The returned object of `fun1` won't be of class `myclass` if you set it _after_ the return statement.

Comment: Maybe `return(out, class="myclass")` works as well in my case... I have define already a `print.myclass` thus when I use normal `mainoutput <- fun1(X)`  typing `mainoutput` returns the output of my `print.myclass` function. I want to add some printed information in the `print.myclass` function which I can get from the starting data frame `X`...thats why i need the starting data frame it in my `prin.myclass` function. But I dont want this information to be visible in my main function output

Comment: I'm confused. `return(out, class="myclass")` is not valid R. What are you talking about? What do you mean by `visible`? Pretty much everything in R is visible (and everything which uses S3 classes). If you need just some information from `X` returns also that information. Maybe you can be more specific stating what is your object and what you want to show with the `print` method.